# Restart MongoDB after crash

Tags: mongodb, database

I ran MongoDB in background in the Ubuntu server with the following command :

```
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongod.log
```

But sometimes database crashes and I have to restart manually, my question is how to restart automatically if database crashes ?

I have tried to add in `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`:

```
respawn
respawn limit 10 90
```

But still if I kill monogodb process it haven't started automatically. What is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending what operating system you are using,  you should use the packages provided for your distribution at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-on-linux/ and then the start scripts provided.

For ubuntu you need to create the systemd file

If you install the .deb package from the link I provided earlier you can then create a systemd script by doing the following.

Create /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service with the contents

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then run 
systemctl start mongodb
systemctl enable mongodb

Then you can use systemctl restart mongodb whenever you want to start.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to create the mongodb service in systemctl on ubuntu if you've installed the .deb from the link I also provided.